# Problemas em inserir um registro datatime

Tags: mysql, sql

Essa é a descrição da minha tabela no MySQL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É assim que estou inseindo os registros

```
insert into pedido
(data_criacao,data_entrega,
entrega_cep,
entrega_cidade,entrega_logradouro,entrega_numero,entrega_uf,
forma_pagamento,status,valor_desconto,valor_frete,valor_total,cliente_id,vendedor_id)
values(2013-08-17 11:25:00,
2013-08-20,34400000,"Uberlandia","Rua das arvores grandes",300,"MG","DINHEIRO","ORCAMENTO",0.00,0.00,1000.00,1,1);
```

Esse é o erro que está aparecendo na tabela;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro está na linha 6, como faço para inserir corretamente o registro;

Answer (score 2):

Valores date, datetime, timestamp assim como os de texto(char, varchar, text etc) precisam estar entre aspas, de preferência as simples, dependendo da configuração do servidor aspas duplas também podem ser usadas para identificar nomes de tabelas, colunas e outros objetos do banco de dados, essa configuração é conhecida como [ansi quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html).

```
insert into pedido
(data_criacao,
data_entrega,
entrega_cep,
entrega_cidade,entrega_logradouro,entrega_numero,entrega_uf,
forma_pagamento,status,
valor_desconto,
valor_frete,
valor_total,
cliente_id,vendedor_id)
values
('2013-08-17 11:25:00',
'2013-08-20',
34400000,
'Uberlandia',
'Rua das arvores grandes',
300,
'MG',
'DINHEIRO',
'ORCAMENTO',
0.00,
0.00,
1000.00,
1,
1);
```